# STL vector containing vector causing segfault

Tags: c++

The following code causes a segfault when I try to issue my `push_back` call.  What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    std::string * foo = new std::string("hello world");
    cout << *foo << endl;

    std::vector<std::vector<std::string *> > my_vecs;
    my_vecs[0].push_back(foo); // segfaults
    cout << "trying to print my_vecs size of " << my_vecs.size() << " but we never reach that point due to segfault " << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I'm pretty sure I'm violating one of the contracts for using `vector`, as the problem is surely not with the STL implementation.

Comment: Ask yourself: In `my_vecs[0].push_back(&foo);` what is the size of `my_vecs`?  Is `0` a valid index?

Comment: Seems like addressing element 0 without having pushed an inner vector in the first place is the problem.  I guess I could fix it by first pushing an empty vector... will try that.

Comment: @nathanoliver, I was hoping that the STL would automatically grow the vector.  It seems that's not the way it's designed.

Comment: That is exactly the problem

Comment: It will grow, but you have to use `push_back` for that.  Just accessing an element that doesn't exist won't automatically create that element (and all the others between the last element and the out of bounds index)

Comment: @ragerdl "_I was hoping that the STL would automatically grow the vector_" When in doubt - read the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead of hoping.

Comment: Additional remark : you push the address of a variable placed into the stack, this is _very_ dangerous because that variable can disappear (I don't speak about the current code), better to use a `vector<string>` or if you really need to push a `string *` allocate it in the heap

Comment: Why all the downvotes?  It's a clear question accompanied by a clear and succinct code sample.  And, it has a clear answer.

Comment: @ragerdl  probably because your problem is trivial (I do not down voted and I do not say that in a wrong way)

Comment: @bruno good point, I've updated the problem to use a string allocated on the heap instead of the stack so that it's more believable that the objects contained in my real problem are pointers.

Comment: @ragerdl Hover over the downvote button: "This question does not show any research effort." Side note: this issue can be reproduced without the use of pointers, so the title is misleading.

Comment: @Algirdas Preidžius fair enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The outer vector must first be explicitly grown, before one can push to its elements.

This may be a little surprising since STL map's automatically insert their keys.  But, it's certainly the way it is.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    const int DESIRED_VECTOR_SIZE = 1;
    std::string * foo = new std::string("hello world");
    cout << *foo << endl;

    std::vector<std::vector<std::string *> > my_vecs;

    for (int i = 0; i < DESIRED_VECTOR_SIZE; ++i) {
        std::vector<std::string *> tmp;
        my_vecs.push_back(tmp); // will invoke copy constructor, which seems unfortunate but meh
    }

    my_vecs[0].push_back(foo); // segfaults
    cout << "now able to print my_vecs size of " << my_vecs.size() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You could simply say `my_vecs.resize(n);` instead of that loop.

Answer (score 1):

When you create `my_vecs` it has 0 elements, hence `my_vecs[0]` does not exists and gives segfault. You have to first reserve at least one element of `my_vecs` and then you can insert in the vector `my_vecs[0]` your pointer:

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::string *> > my_vecs(1);
my_vecs[0].push_back(&foo);
```